# Rotativa - Wkhtmltopdf: Add footer chinese text?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I am trying to add a footer to the page that shows the page number what looks like this 
"Page 1 of 10" in Chinese using Rotativa HTML to PDF library.

This is set by the CustomSwitches attribute.
My code is like this

```
        ViewAsPdf pdfView = new ViewAsPdf("Index", Model)
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            PageOrientation = pageOrientation,
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            IsJavaScriptDisabled = isJavaScriptDisabled,
            CustomSwitches = "--disable-external-links --disable-internal-links --footer-center \"Page [page] of [toPage]\" --footer-font-size 7"
        };
```

This works great.
But if I change the text to Chinese it does not render the characters right

```
--footer-center \"第 [page] 页, 共 [toPage] 页\"
```

I understand the this CustomSwitches calls wkHtmltoPDF, but did not find anything there either. The html page that contains Chinese characters renders just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the custom switches are a command line argument for the WkhtmltoPDF.

In order to make it work you have to go to Control panel -> Region and language -> Administrative -> Change system locale... -> in this case I selected Chinese (Simplified, PRC)